# Laravel 5 getstream.io getUserFeed()

Tags: laravel-5, getstream-io

I'm trying to use getstream.io in my Laravel 5 application. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://$feed%20=%20FeedManager::getUserFeed($user-%3Eid);), but got stuck on this one:

```
$feed = FeedManager::getUserFeed($user->id);
```

When I go to the FeedManager class, I couldn't find the `getUserFeed()` method. Here's how my `FeedManager` class look like:

```
<?php namespace GetStream\StreamLaravel\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class FeedManager extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'feed_manager'; }

}
```

I wonder if I did something wrong during installation. The tutorial said to run `php artisan config:publish get-stream/stream-laravel`, but I did `php artisan vendor:publish get-stream/stream-laravel`. The reason is because I got an error when running `config:publish`, so I used `vendor:publish` instead

Answer (score 1):

The Stream-PHP-Example is now working in Laravel 5, take a look: https://github.com/GetStream/Stream-Example-PHP